# Ubuntu 16.04 blocks after some hours of inactivity

Tags: drivers, 16.04, amd-graphics

I have a problem with Ubuntu 16.04. After some hours of inactivity (e.g. overnight) the system is blocked. The screen remains off, yet the computer continues to work.  For example, the mediaplayer is playing music. But the screen is off, and I can't unlock the system.

System configuration:

- Motherboard ASUS Sabertooth Mark 1
- CPU Intel Core I7-4790
- Ram DDR3 16GB
- Video Radeon R9-270 1GB
- HDD: SSD Corsair 120GB
- Keyboad and mouse - wireless USB, works in DOS, no drivers needed
- OS: Ubuntu 16.04.01 x64

I see this error in my syslog file:

```
Aug 24 10:50:56 default kernel: [36130.934868] amdgpu 0000:01:00.0: GPU fault detected: 146 0x0bb8440c
Aug 24 10:50:56 default kernel: [36130.934871] amdgpu 0000:01:00.0:   VM_CONTEXT1_PROTECTION_FAULT_ADDR   0x00114177
Aug 24 10:50:56 default kernel: [36130.934872] amdgpu 0000:01:00.0:   VM_CONTEXT1_PROTECTION_FAULT_STATUS 0x0804400C
Aug 24 10:50:56 default kernel: [36130.934873] VM fault (0x0c, vmid 4) at page 1130871, read from 'TC7' (0x54433700) (68)
```

After this, I see repeatedly (10 times):

```
Aug 24 10:54:49 default kernel: [36363.986009] INFO: task Xorg:12385 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
Aug 24 10:54:49 default kernel: [36363.986017]       Not tainted 4.4.0-34-generic #53-Ubuntu
Aug 24 10:54:49 default kernel: [36363.986020] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
Aug 24 10:54:49 default kernel: [36363.986025] Xorg            D ffff88042a3c39d0     0 12385   3116 0x00400004
Aug 24 10:54:49 default kernel: [36363.986033]  ffff88042a3c39d0 ffff88042a3c39b0 ffff88042c708dc0 ffff8803b6b40dc0
Aug 24 10:54:49 default kernel: [36363.986040]  ffff88042a3c4000 ffff88002b5b4060 ffff880426bde1c8 ffffffffc021b230
Aug 24 10:54:49 default kernel: [36363.986045]  ffff880426bd8000 ffff88042a3c39e8 ffffffff81829e15 0000000000000000
Aug 24 10:54:49 default kernel: [36363.986051] Call Trace:
Aug 24 10:54:49 default kernel: [36363.986115]  [<ffffffffc021b230>] ? amdgpu_gem_prime_export+0x50/0x50 [amdgpu]
Aug 24 10:54:49 default kernel: [36363.986125]  [<ffffffff81829e15>] schedule+0x35/0x80
Aug 24 10:54:49 default kernel: [36363.986182]  [<ffffffffc025a0fc>] amd_sched_entity_push_job+0x5c/0x100 [amdgpu]
Aug 24 10:54:49 default kernel: [36363.986191]  [<ffffffff810c3ca0>] ? wake_atomic_t_function+0x60/0x60
Aug 24 10:54:49 default kernel: [36363.986244]  [<ffffffffc025a6ea>] amdgpu_sched_ib_submit_kernel_helper+0xda/0x1b0 [amdgpu]
Aug 24 10:54:49 default kernel: [36363.986288]  [<ffffffffc021ba9d>] amdgpu_vm_bo_update_mapping+0x32d/0x5a0 [amdgpu]
Aug 24 10:54:49 default kernel: [36363.986332]  [<ffffffffc021c9f4>] amdgpu_vm_bo_update+0x104/0x290 [amdgpu]
Aug 24 10:54:49 default kernel: [36363.986369]  [<ffffffffc020c7cc>] amdgpu_gem_va_update_vm+0x1ac/0x1d0 [amdgpu]
Aug 24 10:54:49 default kernel: [36363.986410]  [<ffffffffc021cf01>] ? amdgpu_vm_bo_map+0x131/0x490 [amdgpu]
Aug 24 10:54:49 default kernel: [36363.986448]  [<ffffffffc020dac6>] amdgpu_gem_va_ioctl+0x286/0x3f0 [amdgpu]
Aug 24 10:54:49 default kernel: [36363.986480]  [<ffffffffc0098742>] drm_ioctl+0x152/0x540 [drm]
Aug 24 10:54:49 default kernel: [36363.986517]  [<ffffffffc020d840>] ? amdgpu_gem_metadata_ioctl+0x240/0x240 [amdgpu]
Aug 24 10:54:49 default kernel: [36363.986525]  [<ffffffff8120d5a6>] ? do_readv_writev+0x146/0x230
Aug 24 10:54:49 default kernel: [36363.986532]  [<ffffffff813fa039>] ? timerqueue_add+0x59/0xb0
Aug 24 10:54:49 default kernel: [36363.986562]  [<ffffffffc01f604c>] amdgpu_drm_ioctl+0x4c/0x80 [amdgpu]
Aug 24 10:54:49 default kernel: [36363.986567]  [<ffffffff81220c3f>] do_vfs_ioctl+0x29f/0x490
Aug 24 10:54:49 default kernel: [36363.986575]  [<ffffffff81707dd0>] ? __sys_recvmsg+0x80/0x90
Aug 24 10:54:49 default kernel: [36363.986580]  [<ffffffff81220ea9>] SyS_ioctl+0x79/0x90
Aug 24 10:54:49 default kernel: [36363.986585]  [<ffffffff8182def2>] entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x16/0x71
```

Is it the AMD driver?  How do I solve this problem?